# MongoDB two or more $match comparisons on the same field does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This works:

```
    $match: {
        $and: 
        [{ 
            status: {$lt: 4},       
            checkin: {$gte: 1490720400, $lte: 1490806799} 
        }]
    }
```

This does not:

```
    $match: {
        $and: 
        [{ 
            status: {$lt: 4},       
            checkin: {$gte: 1490720400},
            checkin: {$lte: 1490806799}
        }]
    }
```

Why is that?

In the second example it completely ignores the second comparison.

If that is so, then what would happen to this one?

```
    $match:
    { 
        $and: 
        [
            { checkin: {$gte: 1490979600}, checkout: {$lte: 1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1490979600} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1493569439}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} }
        ]
    }
```

Would that be the same?  That it looks at the first one and ignores the next three?

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I believe second example should work if you move $and operator to and checkin values.Something like `$match:{status: {$lt: 4}, {$and:[checkin: {$gte: 1490720400},             checkin: {$lte: 1490806799}         }] }    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ 
    status: {$lt: 4},       
    checkin: {$gte: 1490720400},
    checkin: {$lte: 1490806799}
}
```

is just wrong syntax for JSON documents. The field name should be unique. You declare `checkin` twice, which makes it ambiguous, and it is up to the parser how to resolve it. E.g. in mongodb shell the later value overwrites the former:

```
printjson({ 
    status: {$lt: 4},       
    checkin: {$gte: 1490720400},
    checkin: {$lte: 1490806799}
});
```

results with

```
{
    "status" : {
        "$lt" : 4
    },
    "checkin" : {
        "$lte" : 1490806799
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex.   One more question.  when you do a $match: {lots_of_arguments} and does not specify any $or or $and - are these {lots_of_arguments} all "and" by default?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty well documented in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-and-conditions

Comment: Thanks!!  I was reading the documentation on $match, nothing there hehe.  To be honest, mongos docs are really horrible for the most part.  The examples here on stackoverflow are way better.

Comment: But there is a direct link to the page in $match docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match. Not sure how better it could be, but if you feel like it can be improved, there is an "edit" icon on top right corner of each page.

Answer (score 2):

**Given Ex:1**

```
$match: {
        $and: 
        [{ 
            status: {$lt: 4},       
            checkin: {$gte: 1490720400, $lte: 1490806799} 
        }]
    }
```

In this example there is no ambiguity on field names, so works fine

**Given Ex:2**

```
$match: {
        $and: 
        [{ 
            status: {$lt: 4},       
            checkin: {$gte: 1490720400},
            checkin: {$lte: 1490806799}
        }]
    }
```

Here there is a ambiguity on filed "checkin" so, "checkin" will be overwritten by next "checkin" while constructing the object (it depends which one will be overwritten, usually first will replaced by second)

To make it work you need to use like below

```
$match:
        { 
            $and: 
            [
             {status: {$lt: 4}},       
             {checkin: {$gte: 1493569438} },
             {checkin: {$lte: 1493569440}}
           ]
        }
    }
```

or you can use like in **Given Ex:1**

**Given Ex:3**

```
$match:
    { 
        $and: 
        [
            { checkin: {$gte: 1490979600}, checkout: {$lte: 1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1490979600} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1493569439}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} }
        ]
    }
```

will work fine, i.e It will check all the 4 conditions in $and

Comment: Thanks a lot @Panda.  Quick question, if you do not specify $and or $or when you match on several parameters, what are they pr default?  I would think that "and" would be the default?

Comment: Yes, ex:  '$match:
        { 
             status: {$lte: 5},       
             checkin: {$gte: 1493569439}
        }' , here it behaves like "and"